# Trying to understand Scala Array

Tags: scala, performance, performance-testing

I am trying to evaluate which data structure would be best represent sparse vectors in Scala. These sparse vectors contain a list of indexes, and one value for each index. I implemented a small benchmark, which seems to indicate that an `Array[(Long, Double)]` seems to take a lot less space than 2 parallel arrays. Is that correct? Am I doing that benchmark correctly? (I wouldn't be surprised if I did something wrong somewhere)

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
import java.text.NumberFormat

object TestSize {

  val N = 100000000
  val formatter: NumberFormat = java.text.NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance

  def twoParallelArrays(): Unit = {

    val Z1 = Array.ofDim[Long](N)
    val Z2 = Array.ofDim[Double](N)
    Z1(N-1) = 1
    Z2(N-1) = 1.0D
    println(Z2(N-1) - Z1(N-1))
    val z1 = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage.getUsed
    val z2 = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean.getNonHeapMemoryUsage.getUsed
    println(s"${formatter.format(z1)} ${formatter.format(z2)}")
  }

  def arrayOfTuples(): Unit = {

    val Z = Array.ofDim[(Long, Double)](N)
    Z(N-1) = (1, 1.0D)
    println(Z(N-1)._2 - Z(N-1)._1)
    val z1 = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage.getUsed
    val z2 = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean.getNonHeapMemoryUsage.getUsed
    println(s"${formatter.format(z1)} ${formatter.format(z2)}")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // Comment one or the other to look at the results
    //arrayOfTuples()
    twoParallelArrays()
  }
}
```

Comment: An important point to note about Scala: the case of names is significant. So a name of `Z1` can confuse the compiler (and casual readers). With few exceptions, the Java naming conventions are followed.

Comment: @BobDalgleish - Point taken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not correct.

```
Array.ofDim[(Long, Double)](N)
```

creates a large array filled with `null`, and does not allocate any space for `Long`, `Double`, or the actual `Tuple2`-instance, that's why you don't see anything in heap-memory usage.

The two-array version allocates all the space it needs for all `Long` and `Double` immediately, and you see it in heap space usage.

Just replace `ofDim` by an appropriate `fill` to see the *real* numbers.

On array of size `N = 1000000`:

```
arrayOfTuples:     45,693,312 19,190,296
twoParallelArrays: 25,925,792 19,315,256
```

The `arrayOfTuples`-solution clearly takes more space.

You might wonder why the factor is roughly 1.8 instead of at least 2.5. This is because `Tuple2` is [@specialized](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.4/src/library/scala/Tuple2.scala#L1) for a few primitive datatypes, especially for `Long` and `Double`, therefore these two 8-byte primitives can be stored in `Tuple2` without boxing. Therefore, the total overhead is only 8 bytes for a 64-bit reference from array to `Tuple2`, and some overhead in each `Tuple2` instance. But still, it's more than storing `Long` and `Double` directly in arrays.

By the way: that's exactly the reason why Apache Spark stores the data using all those `Encoder`s: so that you don't have to worry about the overhead caused by your tuples and case-classes.

---

Full code:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
import java.text.NumberFormat

object TestSize {

  val N = 1000000
  val formatter: NumberFormat = java.text.NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance

  def twoParallelArrays(): Unit = {

    val Z1 = Array.fill[Long](N)(42L)
    val Z2 = Array.fill[Double](N)(42.0)
    println(Z1)
    println(Z2)
    Z1(N-1) = 1
    Z2(N-1) = 1.0D
    println(Z2(N-1) - Z1(N-1))
    val z1 = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage.getUsed
    val z2 = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean.getNonHeapMemoryUsage.getUsed
    Z1((new scala.util.Random).nextInt(N)) = 1234L
    Z2((new scala.util.Random).nextInt(N)) = 345.0d
    println(Z2(N-1) - Z1(N-1))
    println(s"${formatter.format(z1)} ${formatter.format(z2)}")
  }

  def arrayOfTuples(): Unit = {

    val Z = Array.fill[(Long, Double)](N)((42L, 42.0d))
    Z(N-1) = (1, 1.0D)
    println(Z(N-1)._2 - Z(N-1)._1)
    val z1 = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage.getUsed
    val z2 = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean.getNonHeapMemoryUsage.getUsed
    Z((new scala.util.Random).nextInt(N)) = (1234L, 543.0d)
    println(Z(N-1)._2 - Z(N-1)._1)
    println(s"${formatter.format(z1)} ${formatter.format(z2)}")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // Comment one or the other to look at the results
    arrayOfTuples()
    // twoParallelArrays()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andrey! Perfect - I should have initialized/filled these arrays. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Frank Seems obvious in hindsight, but I've found the output actually quite surprising for a moment. And nice to recall the fact that `Tuple2` is `@specialized`, so thank you too for the question :)